# Kendo UI: Combo box shows value instead of Text

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using Kendo UI with AngularJS. I am having trouble fixing an issue.

If a model is set to an ID which is not present in the datasource the combobox is bound to, the value is shown in the dropdown as is. i.e. if I set the model to 4 and there is no data item in datasource with ID 4, the combobox shows 4 as is. I want to replace it with empty string.
How can I change it to show empty textbox instead?

see the [sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/EfaLe)

PS. the problem is not limited to Angular. Kendo's own MVVM binding has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since it is not dropdown but combobox and so you can write every text inside it, I am afraid you will have to make your own check.

Value property just set a value and in case of combo box, if value not match with item in data source then it just set value to the input box.

To make a check I would use [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-dataSource) event which is started once after component is created. Because it is launched after component is created you can easily compare selected value with values in data source.

Small [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EfaLe/4) here. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to the party but the accepted answer did not work for me.

If anyone is using SQL server to store their values with a parent table with the foreign key and then a child table where all the combobox values are stored. then what I did was return the ID and Text of the selected value (using left outer join).

EDIT: I just noticed this is angular, the below is for **kendo-ui Jquery**.

---

### SQL

```
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        ChildID,                -- ID stored in parent table
        childTable.ChildDesc    -- Getting child text 
FROM    parentTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN childTable ON childTable.ChildID = parentTable.ChildID
```

---

### JS

```
$("#id").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "Description",
    dataValueField: "ID",
    filter: "contains",
    minLength: 1,
    filtering: onFilterCostCentre,
    value: item.ChildID,
    text: item.ChildDesc
})
```